# Angular 6 include google closure library

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I want to include [google closure library](https://github.com/google/closure-library) into my angular 6 application. I have applied

`npm install google-closure-compiler` and `npm install google-closure-library`.

The app can be compiled and running. However, when I trying to run the tests I wrote with `ng test`, it has error messages:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/boostrap/nodejs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in './node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/bootstrap'

ERROR in ./node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/promise/testsuiteadapter.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promises_aplus_tests' in './node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/promise/testsuiteadapter.js'
```

I use the angular official [demo](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) example and I just added the test and installed these two libraries. My guesses are I need to configure `karma.conf.js`, but I don't know how to do that, does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your webpack config

```
node: {
  fs: 'empty'
}
```

You can also see how its implemented with this

https://github.com/angular/closure-demo